# Perform update on row from entity framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I would like to update a row like this:

```
update [approvers] set approvalstatus = True Where approvalstatus = False and bookingID = @bookingid and approveremail = @email
```

Using the entity framework.

I have my query which should deliver the item like so:

```
Dim db As New Model.Entities
Dim approvers = From a In db.approvers Where a.ApprovalStatus = False And a.BookingID = BookingID And a.ApproverEmail = UserName Select a.ApprovalStatus
```

How do I next target this record for update, so that I can set a.approvalStatus = True then commit these changes to the db?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Dim approver As Model.Approvers = (From a In db.Approvers Where a.ApprovalStatus = False And a.ApproverEmail = UserName And a.BookingID = BookingID).First

        approver.ApprovalStatus = True
        db.SaveChanges()
```